# .htaccess and subdirectories

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to make a .htaccess file that is basically a wildcard setup. I have a folder structure as below.

```
public_html/sites is the root directory and in this folder there are two sub directories:

public_html/sites/brand (there are many brand folders, just used brand as example)
public_html/sites/brand/event (there are many events in a brand folder, just used event as example)

I have files in each event folder such as index.php and media.php
```

I have been unsuccessful in rewriting the media page to the URL structure I am looking for. Below is my current .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^media/([^/]*)$ /media.php?unqid=$1 [L]
```

So the expected URL I am wanting is /testbrand/4177/media/123456. I will have serveral brands and several events under each brand so I am needing some sort of wildcard if possible. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I will have several brand folders I just showed one as example. The directory are created on the fly each time a new brand is added in our system. In the sites folder I have over 30 brands at this time and they all share the same folder structure. Due to the fact they are created on the fly I need some type of wildcard as these are created systematically.

Comment: well basically I am wanting to have media.php?unqmid=123456 in the event folder be rewritten to /media/123456. So basically media.php?media.php?unqmid=123456 turns into testbrand/4177/media/123456, however I need this .htaccess rewrite to work for all brands and events not just testbrand and eventid 4177.

Comment: 4177 is the eventid (a subdirectory of testbrand), testbrand is a subdirectory of sites

Comment: OP updated to better explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]+/[^/]+)/media/(\d+)/?$ $1/media.php?unqid=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

This will load `/testbrand/4177/media.php?unqid=123456` when you request `/testbrand/4177/media/123456`

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works for the most part, however, the $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] is passing as unqmid=testbrand/4177 instead of the unqid, any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Ah my mistake it should have been `$2` in target. Try my updated rule now.

Answer (score 2):

If you are wanting to have a URL like this

```
http://example.com/testbrand/4177/media/123456
```

And your brands are dynamic, then your rewrite **should** *probably* look something like this.

```
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]+)/(?:[0-9]+)/media/([0-9]+)/?$ /media.php?unqid=$1 [L]
```

Based on your current internal URL you'll only be sending the id number that comes after `/media/` to PHP. If you have more info you need to send, then you need to update your internal URI parameters.